# USB OTG circuit for device drawing more current

Tags: usb

I have an android phone that supports USB OTG. I want to connect a midi keyboard to the phone via USB but it is not working, I suspect because the phone cannot supply the required current.

Is it acceptable and safe for my electronics for me to connect an external 5V power supply  to the GND and VCC pins?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxr66L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Test with a powered USB hub to confirm that power is the limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a diode in order not to inject current from the external 5 V power supply into the 5 V power supply of your phone.

Use a common diode like 1N4148.

Connect the anode of the diode to the 5V of the phone and the cathod to the external 5 V power supply.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe.  USB is a high speed interface and so does not react well to having the cables modified by users.  Modifying a cable to inject power is likely to cause damage and is not likely to work because it will disrupt the finely tuned transmission line between the phone and keyboard.  Use a powered hub to get more power to USB devices.

USB-OTG specifies a means for a dock or hub to supply power to the phone and to connected peripherals, you may want to look into such products as a solution.

Comment: I mean technically you are correct, but with USB 2.0 I have used cables cut open, with flying wires tied together by hand... You aren't going to get blazing speeds but there are good chances it will work, and might be enough for a midi keyboard.